# how to maintain the orginal size of image of button in android?

Tags: android

when I add image for button in android using setBackgroundResource mthe height of the image changes ,, how can i maintian the original height of of the image on the button ??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can specify layout_height and layout_weight values to "wrap_Content"